# how to create Slack app a legacy token for the respective workspace using command?

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-api

I want to use the undocumented API method [chat.command](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/chat.command.md), but this API method allows legacy tokens only.

However, slack app's doe not provide legacy tokens.

How to I create legacy tokens with a slack app?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create legacy tokens with Slack apps. The only way to create a legacy token is by creating them manually for your respective workspace using this link:

https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens

Legacy tokens where meant as an easy way to create test tokens for development, not to be used with production apps and/or Slack apps that are to be distributed to other workspaces.

While they are still very useful if you want to use [undocumented API methods](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc), they are officially not recommend to be used and due to there restrictions basically only make sense to be used for your own workspace.